# Custom user view/edit permissions related to same table for different users in django admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-admin

i am making an survey/polling app using django rest framework. I have  a polls table, and personality's table (with a django country Field in it) related to poll table. I am using rest-auth for user model (not related to personality table). Now i need set some permissions in  django admin panel that a certain admin can only view a poll for certain country only.
like for example, if there is an admin for US, then he can view/add/change only the polls related to US only.
is there any way to set such permissions.
**NOTE:** these permissions are needed to be set for admin panel

Comment: Welcome to the community. Think i understood your question. However, next time you can try sharing some images or diagrams or maybe a chunk of code that helps readers understand your question better. 
Meanwhile i think what you are looking for is : https://github.com/dfunckt/django-rules

Comment: thanks for the reply, i'm still new here. the link you shared is quite helpful